# IdentityServer 4: how can I add a custom external authentication?

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 and I would like to add a custom external provider.
in the doc, I saw that I can use AddGoogle, AddGitHut etc
but there is no AddCustom.
I would like to use an old legacy system, based on the CAS protocol.

many thanks
Pierre

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom external provider using OpenID Connect.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddOpenIdConnect("schema", "name", options =>
        {
            // ...
        });
```

Read more [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html#adding-authentication-handlers-for-external-providers)

Also checkout this [repo](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers), it contains a collection OAuth 2.0 social authentication providers for ASP.NET Core. In case you needed to add a custom middleware the code on this repo may come handy.

Comment: thank you nadidf,
I'll try both solutions (addOpenIdConnect & middleware)

Comment: @PierreMotoc any luck?